# Select com vários Left Joins Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Peguei um exemplo de cadastro de pessoas com a seguinte estrutura: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer um `SELECT` na `tblPessoa` com `JOIN` com a intenção de que o select retorne os dados da tabela na qual o Id exista, segue select:

```
select tblPessoaJuridica.Nome as [NomePJ], tblPessoaFisica.Nome as [NomePF], tblPessoaProdutor.Nome as [NomeProdutor] 
from tblPessoa 
left join tblPessoaFisica on tblPessoaFisica.IdPessoaFisica = tblPessoa.idPessoa
left join tblPessoaJuridica on tblPessoaJuridica.IdPessoaJuridica = tblPessoa.idPessoa 
left join tblPessoaProdutor on tblPessoaProdutor.IdPessoaProdutor = tblPessoa.idPessoa
where idPessoa = 2547
```

Porem tenho lido que o left join é lento, exemplo:

[Slow query in SQL Server with left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497249/slow-query-in-sql-server-with-left-join)

[Left Joins are what I want but they are very slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628685/left-joins-are-what-i-want-but-they-are-very-slow)

entre outros.

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente de substituir este left join ?

**EDIT**

Eu coloquei 'NOME' só para exemplo, a PJ tem Razão Social, a PF tem o Nome e o Produtor tem o nome da Fazenda/Sitio/Etc. Esse diagrama é um exemplo que peguei.

Comment: Que eu saiba não tem a tal forma eficiente para substituir o left join e retornar os mesmo registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `UNION` que irá "concatenar" os resultados de `querys` que tenham as mesmas definições de colunas resultantes. Assim você pode montar um retorno das pessoas com seus devidos tipos.

> [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180026.aspx)
>
> Combina os resultados de duas ou mais consultas em um único conjunto de resultados, que inclui todas as linhas pertencentes a todas as consultas da união. A operação UNION é diferente de usar junções que combinam colunas de duas tabelas.
>
> A seguir são apresentadas as regras básicas de combinação dos conjuntos de resultados de duas consultas usando UNION:
>
> - O número e a ordem das colunas devem ser iguais em todas as consultas.
> - Os tipos de dados devem ser compatíveis.

Abaixo como ficaria com o esquema que você determinou.

```
SELECT tpj.nome,
       'J' as tipo
  FROM tblPessoaJuridica tpj
  INNER JOIN tblPessoa tp ON tp.idPessoaJuridica = tpj.idPessoaFisica
UNION
SELECT tpf.nome,
       'F' as tipo
  FROM tblPessoaFisica tpf
  INNER JOIN tblPessoa tp ON tp.idPessoa = tpf.idPessoaFisica
UNION
SELECT tpp.nome,
       'P' as tipo
  FROM tblPessoaProdutor tpp
  INNER JOIN tblPessoa tp ON tp.idPessoa = tpp.idPessoaProdutor
```

Você pode usar o select acima de criar uma `view` que facilitará o reuso.

> [VIEW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/ms187956.aspx)
>
> Cria uma tabela virtual cujo conteúdo (colunas e linhas) é definido por uma consulta. Use esta instrução para criar uma exibição dos dados em uma ou mais tabelas no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Crie um ID para identificar o tipo de pessoa e na programação utilize este id para selecionar as informações.

Exemplo:

Meu IDPessoa é 555 e meu IDTipoPessoa é 2 (Pessoa fisica):

```
if(IDTipoPessoa == 1){

}else if(IDTipoPessoa == 2){

}else if(IDTipoPessoa == 3){

}else{
   //retorna erro tipo inválido
}
```

Sempre que possuir um novo tipo é só adicionar um else.
Ou coloque faça o seguinte, coloque tudo em uma mesma tabela, seja ele Produto/Pessoa Física ou Juridica e o select fica assim:

```
     SELECT COALESCE(CNPJ,CPF,nomeProduto,'ERRO') as NOME FROM tblPessoa 
JOIN tblinformacoes on idPessoa = FKidPessoa
```

Acho que poderia ser assim, depende mais da sua regra de negócio.
Abraço,

Answer (score 0):

Não considerando a hipótese de reestruturar as suas tabelas, é bem provável que o `LEFT JOIN` seja a melhor alternativa afinal de contas.

Além disso, você só deveria estar se preocupando com o desempenho neste caso se você realmente tiver evidências de que isto esteja engargalando o seu sistema. Neste caso, uma possível solução seria a de copiar os dados em uma outra tabela de cache com uma estrutura desnormalizada para agilizar a consulta, ou então manter essa tabela ou partes dela em memória. Entretanto, essas coisas é algo que você só vai pensar em fazer se tiver uma real necessidade para tal.

Uma outra possibilidade é certificar-se que todas as três tabelas tenham registros para cada ID da `tblPessoa`, mesmo que preenchido com um monte de nulos e com isso trocar os `LEFT JOIN`s por `INNER JOIN`s. Entretanto, se você for fazer essa gambiarra, já seria melhor alterar a estrutura das tabelas.

Answer (score -1):

- Primeiro suas tabelas estão erradas
- Se **nome** é comum a todos, então deve estar na tabela pai
- Campos comuns fica na tabela pai
- Na tabela pai você deve definir um tipo, que represente, que tipo é cada pessoa
- Sim pode ser lento, porque mapeia errado e não criam os índices corretos.
- Outra forma de se fazer é com **subconsulta** em vez de **left jon**

Comment: Eu coloquei 'NOME' só para exemplo, a PJ tem Razão Social, a PF tem o Nome e o Produtor tem o nome da Fazenda/Sitio/Etc. Eu fiz um exemplo somente. Mas vou editar a pergunta e reforçar que o campo 'NOME' é só exemplo.